# Delete rows based on multiple conditions in r

Tags: r

I want to delete some rows based on two conditions. 
Here is my code

```
test <-datasetjoin[!(datasetjoin$Occupation == "Clerical" & datasetjoin$AvgMonthSpend > 58.515 ),]  
test <- test[!(test$Occupation == "Management" & test$AvgMonthSpend > 59.24 ),] 
test <- test[!(test$Occupation == "Manual" & test$AvgMonthSpend > 54.28 ),] 
test <- test[!(test$Occupation == "Professional" & test$AvgMonthSpend > 60.08 ),]   
test <- test[!(test$Occupation == "Skilled Manual" & test$AvgMonthSpend > 57.06 ),] 
test <- test[!(test$NumberCarsOwned == "1" & test$YearlyIncome > (81300-51140) * 1.5 + 81300),]
```

Is it possible to get the same result in a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance

```
Occupation MonthlySpend 
Clerical   60           
Management 59           
Clerical   62           
Clerical   58           
Clerical   63              
Management 56
Management 58
```

If Occupation = clerical and MonthlySpend > 60 then drop these rows
If Occupation = management and MonthlySpend > 57 then drop these rows.
At the end I should get this:

```
Occupation MonthlySpend
Clerical   58
Management 56
```

Comment: Please provide [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for your question.

Comment: @AdamQuek Please check the post, I edited with an example. Is there a way to do this with a loop ? or apply() ?

Answer (score 15):

Combine all conditions by using OR :`|`

Like:

```
test <- test[!(test$Occupation == "Management" & test$AvgMonthSpend > 59.24 ) | !(test$Occupation == "Manual" & test$AvgMonthSpend > 54.28 ),]
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this.

step 1. define the limits :

```
df <- read.table(text="Occupation MonthlySpend 
Clerical   60           
Management 59           
Clerical   62           
Clerical   58           
Clerical   63              
Management 56
Management 58 ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text="Occupation lmt 
Clerical   60           
Management 57           
", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Step2. Join and filter

```
df %>% left_join(df2, by = "Occupation") %>%
  group_by(Occupation) %>%
  filter(MonthlySpend < lmt ) %>%
  select(MonthlySpend)
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: Occupation [2]

  Occupation MonthlySpend
       <chr>        <int>
1   Clerical           58
2 Management           56
```

This way, you have to spend some resources in defining the second dataframe, but the actual process of filtering is streamlined.