# Delete rows with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I have tried to look through these examples https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/delete-or-drop-rows-in-r-with-conditions-2/
[Delete rows based on multiple conditions in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445566/delete-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-r)
but its now working on my code

I seem to be able to delete all of station 7, or not delete any, but I only want to delete depth 1 and depth 2 of station 7 but keep depth 3. Is this possible?

```
 Station <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7,7,8, 8, 8, 9, 9,9)
 Depth <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3)
 Value <- c(5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 3, 6, 3, 8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 6, 9, 1, 3, 456, 321, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 6, 8)

 df <- data.frame(Station, Depth, Value)
 df

 a <- df[!(df$Station == 7 & df$Depth == 1 ) | !(df$Station == 7  & df$Depth == 2 ),] 
  a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
a <- df[!( (df$Station == 7 & df$Depth == 1 ) | (df$Station == 7  & df$Depth == 2 )),] 
a
```

or more compact one

```
a <- df[!( df$Station == 7 & (df$Depth == 1  |  df$Depth == 2 )),] 
a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of ways to write this -

```
subset(df, !(Station == 7 & Depth %in% 1:2))
```

Or -

```
subset(df, Station != 7 | Station == 7 & Depth == 3)
```

The same expression can also be used in `dplyr::filter` if you prefer that.